# Not able load google map inside webview in local html file

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3

I am using a local html file named basicmap.html which contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                                              scrollwheel: false,
                                              zoom: 8
                                              });
                                              console.log(map);
            }

            </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCvjeJZDdkpxCLasVMvTX2raxKkVGUULP8&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In viewcontroller.m load local basicmap.html file into webview which have following code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"basicmap" withExtension:@"html"];
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

}
@end
```

Output shows a blank page in webview.

Comment: I also add  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict> in info.plist file

Comment: use this method - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL

Comment: @Jigar 
I use this
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"basic" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

But this also not works/

Comment: you check your html file working or not?

Comment: @Jigar 
Html page is also showing blank in Safari/Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function init() {
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(23.0225, 72.5714);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: latlong,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

and use this method

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Comment: @Sudipta Chatterjee you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Info.plist add key and value

instead of google.com add your link url

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>New item</key>
            <string>http://www.google.com</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

then add the following code to load the  link

```
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
[self.loadwebs loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Here loadwebs is the webview property name